# How can I export a DIV to an Image

Tags: javascript, image, export, png, two.js

I'd like to export a div to a PNG or JPG image. Basically the div has an appended a two.js object. [Two.js](http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js) draws with SVG which means I can't use those canvas `toDataURL` alternatives I guess.

The two.js instance is a 400 by 400px box including a basic grid (horizontal & vertical lines) made using `two.makeLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)`.

JavaScript should return a generated image/screenshot of that div or two.js object if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always switch the rendering contexts in two.js and two.js *always* provides a reference to the elements it creates. e.g:

```
var two = new Two({ type: Two.Types.canvas }).appendTo(document.body);
var canvas = two.renderer.domElement;
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
// Though this data will be blank because there's nothing being rendered.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at a way to plot your SVG into a canvas. Then `toDataURL`-ing the result.

I haven't personally used it, but canvg could be a start: https://code.google.com/p/canvg/